# Formatting font, spacing for references title page header (natbib, report document class)

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

I am creating a template for use in Report document class with pdfLaTeX compiler in Overleaf.

I have been able to format the chapter headers, section headers, etc. I am having trouble formatting the references back matter. The gap between the "REFERENCES" title is too large for the requirements I am trying to match.

How can I control the gaps for the References header (above and below)? The gaps for the other chapters/headers is set correctly. All the formatting is included below in case there are some upstream conflicts that will matter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

% page, paragraph dimensions
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

% use Calibri font
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}

% headings
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{22pt}{0pt}\bfseries}%
    {\thechapter}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{80pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\bfseries}%
    {\thesection}{0.5in}{\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}

% report frontmatter, mainmatter, backmatter
\makeatletter
\newcommand\frontmatter{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand\backmatter{
    \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
    \else
        \clearpage
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% gap between text and figure/table
\setlength{\intextsep}{24pt}

% references title page
\renewcommand{\bibname}{%
    \fontsize{14pt}{0pt}%
    \begin{center} REFERENCES \end{center}%
    }\titlespacing*{\bibname}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\def\bibfont{\fontsize{11pt}{0pt}\selectfont\hyphenpenalty=10000}
% TRIED WITH NO EFFECT
% \titlespacing*{\bibname}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\title{template}
\author{none}
\date{\today}

\frontmatter

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\cite{einstein1906new}

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, `references.bib` contents:

```
@article{einstein1906new,
  title={A new determination of molecular dimensions},
  author={Einstein, Albert},
  journal={Ann. Phys.},
  volume={19},
  pages={289--306},
  year={1906}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead add something to the processing of `thebibliography`, namely a (local) change in the parameters for `\titleformat`. I also suggest how to add the references to the table of contents

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein1906new,
  title={A new determination of molecular dimensions},
  author={Einstein, Albert},
  journal={Ann. Phys.},
  volume={19},
  pages={289--306},
  year={1906}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{natbib}

% page, paragraph dimensions
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

% use Calibri font
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}

% headings
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{22pt}{0pt}\bfseries\filcenter}%
    {\thechapter}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{80pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\bfseries}%
    {\thesection}{0.5in}{\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}

% report frontmatter, mainmatter, backmatter
\makeatletter
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}%
}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}%
}
\newcommand\backmatter{%
    \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
    \else
        \clearpage
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% gap between text and figure/table
\setlength{\intextsep}{24pt}

\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{22pt}{0pt}\bfseries\filcenter}%
    {\thechapter}{0.5in}{\MakeUppercase}%
    %\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{80pt}{40pt}% maybe adjust the spacing
}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\AddToHook{cmd/bibsection/after}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
}

%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\title{template}
\author{none}
\date{\today}

\frontmatter

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\cite{einstein1906new}

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're running LaTeX prior to the 2020-10-01 release, you need to add `\usepackage{etoolbox}` for `\AtBeginEnvironment` and change `\AddToHook{cmd/bibsection/after}` into `\appto{\bibsection}`.

As a stylistic remark, using both nonzero indentation and vertical skip between paragraphs is too much. Use just one (and I mean the former).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, TOC part, and style tips, very much appreciated